# Using read_csv specifying data types for groups of columns in R

Tags: r, select, col

I would like to use read_csv because I am working with a large data. The types of variables are reading incorrectly because I have many missing values. It would be possible to identify the type of variable (column) from the name of the variable, because it includes "DATE" if it is a date-type, "Names" if it is a character type and a rest of the variables can have a default 'col_guess' type. I do not want to type all the 55 variables so I tried this code first:

```
df <- read_csv('df.csv', col_types = cols((grepl("DATE$", colnames(df))==T)=col_date()), cols((grepl("Name$", colnames(df))==T)=col_character()))
```

I received tghis message:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "df <- read_csv('df.csv', col_types = cols((grepl("DATE$", colnames(df))==T)="
```

So I tried to write a loop and because the df data is already in R (but the wrongly identified data variables' values have been deleted).

```
for (colname in colnames(df)){
   if (grepl("DATE$", colname)==T){
    ct1 <- cols(colname=col_date("%d/%m/%Y"))
   }else if (grepl("Name$", colname)==T){
    ct2 <- cols(colname=col_character())
   }else{
    ct3 <- cols(colname=col_guess())  
    tx <- c(ct1, ct2, ct3)
    print(tx)
 }
}
```

It does not do what I would like to get as an output and I do not know how I would need to continue if I would get the loop right. 
The data is a public data, you can download it here (BasicCompanyDataAsOneFile): http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html 
Any suggestion would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is already read in R, you can identify the columns by their names and apply the function to their respective columns.

```
df <- readr::read_csv('df.csv')
date_cols <- grep('DATE$', names(df))
char_cols <- grep('Name$', names(df))

df[date_cols] <- lapply(df[date_cols], as.Date)
df[char_cols] <- lapply(df[char_cols], as.character)
```

You can also try `type.convert` which automatically changes data to their respective types but it might not work for date columns.

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I need to define the type of the character while R is reading in it because otherwise it is loosing those values which do not align with the guessed type of column.

Comment: @Malna Can you read all of them as characters then so that no information is lost and change the column types later ?

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I did. You can see my solution in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I read the data in using read_csv
     `df <- read_csv('DF.csv', col_types = cols(.default="c"))`
then I used the following codes for changing the columns' data types
     `date_cols <- grep('DATE$', names(df))`
     `df[date_cols] <- lapply(df[date_cols], as.Date)`